# C# button to add numbers (duplicating first instance) in stead of adding them

Tags: c#

I'm making a blackjack project - so far, I've made the switch case scenario to generate random numbers - but now I'd like to either A.) make a calculation class for all this - or should I B.) do this calculation via the button?

It makes sense to make a calc class however my variable scope is out, so I'm forced to do it within the button.

This is not my MAIN concern however; I'd like to add the first instance of the switch case "Hit.GenerateID(stRefID)" with the second instance of it.

However I'm not sure how to programitically use new to differentiate between the two, so the result I am getting is (2) = 22.

Hit class:

```
 namespace Blackjack
 {
    public class Hit
    {

        public static string GenerateID(string stRefID)
        {

            Random random = new Random();

                int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(1, 1);

                int two = 2;
                int three = 3;
                int four = 4;
                int five = 5;
                int six = 6;
                int seven = 7;
                int eight = 8;
                int nine = 9;
                int ten = 10;
                int jack = 10;
                int queen = 10;
                int king = 10;
                int ace = 11;


             for (int x = 1; x <= iChosenMaxSize; x++)
             {
                int iCharType = random.Next(0, 12);
                switch (iCharType)
                {
                        case 0:
                            stRefID += two;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            stRefID += three;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            stRefID += four;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            stRefID += five;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            stRefID += six;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            stRefID += seven;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            stRefID += eight;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            stRefID += nine;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            stRefID += ten;
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            stRefID += ace;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            stRefID += jack;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            stRefID += queen;
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            stRefID += king;
                            break;


                    }
              } return stRefID; 

            }
        }
    }
```

Button:

```
 private void hit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string stRefID = "";
        this.playerScore.Text = Hit.GenerateID(stRefID);

        int cardOne;
        cardOne = Convert.ToInt32(this.playerScore.Text);
        int cardTwo;
        cardTwo = new Hit.GenerateID(stRefID);
        this.test.Text = cardTwo.ToString() + cardOne;
 }
```

Comment: What is the result that you expect? Why do you pass `stRefID` into `GenerateID` function, I dont see you using `stRefID` inside the function other that using it as a variable to return...

Comment: When I click hit - it returns that variable; for instance 4, when he clicks hit again I want it to return the new number and add it to the old.

Comment: Looks like your random max and min are `1`. You need to update it to get a new number like 1 to 100 `int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(1, 100)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your GenerateID method could be hugely simplified by using an enum to represent the values of each card.

`public enum CardType {
        Two = 2,
        ...
        Queen = 10,
        King = 10,
        Ace = 11
    }`

1. You need to keep track of each Card that a Player receives. Maybe you should have a Player class that holds the Cards they have been hit with?

Something like this:

```
private Player _player;

private void hit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Add the first card
    _player.Cards.Add(Hit.GenerateID(..));
    // Add the second card
    _player.Cards.Add(Hit.GenerateID(..));
    ...
    // In order to use sum you will need: using System.Linq;
    this.test.Text = _player.Cards.Sum().ToString();
}

public class Player {
    public Player () {
        Cards = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> Cards { get; private set; }
}
```

1. To avoid lots of conversions  you could make GenerateID return int

Comment: Hey Hubris this appears to be right - by my logic but I can't make use of "Cards = new List<int>();"  // Error 1 The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: You need to have: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: ok I think it's half working - I altered your part public Player _player = new Player(); as it kept throwing null error issue...  I tried to change everything to int to prevent the redundant conversions - but now it's calling the local stref ID where I initialize it... Guess I'll just keep at it - thank you very much though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you think you're performing a mathematical addition operation, but you're actually converting an integer to a string, then concatenating that to the end of stRefID.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code looks like the `Random` `Min` and `Max` values are the same (i.e `1` ).
This could be a reason why you get the same value always..

You could update it to generate new random numbers (say 1 to 99)

```
 int iChosenMaxSize = random.Next(1, 99);
```